# Allocate Memory for an array of char pointers? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to layout an array of character pointers from a file.  Here is my attempt:

```
    char c; //in_file is a FILE object
    char** mazestring = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    while((c = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF) {
            mazestring = realloc(mazestring,sizeof(char*)+sizeof(mazestring));
            char *cp = malloc(sizeof(char*));
            *cp = c;
    }
```

When i wrote this code, i was unsure so pardon the nooby code.  I keep getting a seg fault whenever i attempt to run.

Comment: `sizeof(mazestring)` doesn't work/is constant = size of pointer. you have to keep track of the size some other way.

Comment: Also, there's a memory leak at `char *cp = malloc(sizeof(char*));`. You don't free it.

Comment: I did not realize it was the sizeof problem, thank you

Comment: "sizeof" is a compile-time operator. It can't possibly know what you allocate at runtime.

Comment: `char *cp = malloc(sizeof(char*));` Is wrong. That creates space for the size of a pointer, not the size of a char.